# Coldfusion cflog not adding any text to log file

Tags: debugging, logging, coldfusion, lucee

I feel ridiculous for even having to ask this question but not being able to print to a simple log file after an hour and a half is absurd. All I am trying to do is write "okok" to a log file and I can't even get that to work. I am using Lucee coldfusion. Here is my code:

```
 <cflog file="logFile" application="no" text="okok" type="information">
```

The file "logFile" is in the same directory as everything else. What in the world am I missing? There are no errors there is just never anything added to the log file.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `same directory as everything else`?

Comment: I don't know how to be more straightfoward than that so I took a picture of the folder to show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on cflog](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflog.html) has the answer.  Look at the description of the file attribute.  The key sentence is, `The file must be located in the default log directory.`

[This link](https://www.ortussolutions.com/blog/where-are-my-lucee-and-adobe-coldfusion-log-files-on-commandbox-servers), will help you find that directory.

Comment: Thank you I got it finally. I thought the problem might be the location but I couldn't figure out where it was supposed to be.